# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://checkout.url.com/9282' has been blocked by CORS policy: Laravel

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I got error when trying to redirect to an external url. I added the fruitcake/laravel-cors package to my project and updated the configuration cors, but nothing worked. I used Jetstream Laravel with inertiajs stack. The following error was thrown:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://checkout.paystack.com/cfgbfg335' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8000/distributors/purchase-package') from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

// Config cors

'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,

// Code

```
return redirect()->away("checkout.url.com/9282");
```

Have been trying to figure out how to fix this error. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's a redirect to a direct link within another application. That error did not come from Laravel, did it come from Inertia?

Comment: Yes it was from inertia please